# Why did James Gunn direct all those Stan Lee cameos?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, stan-lee

Apparently, James Gunn directed a whole lot of Stan Lee cameos, including and not limited to *Guardians of the Galaxy*, *Doctor Strange*, *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*, *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, and *Thor: Ragnarok*. Why? I mean, it makes sense as to why he directed the ones in his own movies, but why in all the other movies?

Comment: Because Stan Lee is going to die soon and they can use CGI to add these cameos into other films.

Comment: Because Stan Lee died recently and now they can use CGI to add these cameos into other films.

Comment: @Valorum: are *you* the Watcher???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stan Lee was an elderly man and although Marvel wanted to have him cameo in their upcoming films, having him travel across the world to different locations just to film a single short scene was likely to put a strain on both Lee and the film's budget. Better to film a bunch of them all at the same time (against a blue screen) and use CGI to add in the main cast.

> “It’s a big deal for a 93-year-old man to go to a movie set and spend
> a day shooting,” Derrickson explained after a special screening of
> Doctor Strange at EW PopFest.
>
> <sub><sup>[James Gunn comments on directing Stan Lee Marvel cameos](https://www.ew.com/article/2016/10/29/james-gunn-stan-lee-marvel-cameos/)</sup></sub>

Kevin Feige claimed at the time that his cameos were "very specific" but it's since become apparent (to anyone with eyes) that with minor tweaks, the scenes filmed can be changed to suit pretty much any Marvel movie (Stan on bus reading in front of green screen, Stan pretending to drive a bus in front of a green screen, Stan sitting down talking in front of a green screen, Stan in a window talking, etc.)

> "We do not shoot random ones. They're always very specific," Feige
> said during the Q&A. "A couple of months ago in Atlanta, he flew down
> and we shot four in one day — for four various projects."
>
> <sub><sup>[Stan Lee, 93, shot 4 Marvel cameos in one day, and made it look easy](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/movies/la-et-mn-stan-lee-marvel-cameos-20160928-snap-story.html)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 12):

Because Stan Lee is old and filming is a rough business.

> “It’s a big deal for a 93-year-old man to go to a movie set and spend
>   a day shooting,” Derrickson explained after a special screening of
>   Doctor Strange at EW PopFest.
>
> As a result, Lee packed his cameos into one afternoon. “James shot
>   four cameos with Stan in one day,” Derrickson said, adding that Gunn
>   made sure to check with the filmmaker to make sure he did the job
>   right.

(src: [James Gunn comments on directing Stan Lee Marvel cameos](https://ew.com/article/2016/10/29/james-gunn-stan-lee-marvel-cameos/))

Comment: I just said that :-)

Comment: 33 seconds too slow. Story of my life.

Comment: You know what they say about the early bird...